# Python - How can I replace multiple output lines?

Tags: python, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I have three outputs and I want to replace it in every 3 seconds.

With this code it's printing only the c:

```
import sys

import time

a = 1

b = 5

c =10

while True:

  sys.stdout.write("\r" + str(a))

  sys.stdout.write("\r" + str(b))

  sys.stdout.write("\r" + str(c))

  time.sleep(3)

  a += 1

  b+=1

  c+=1

  sys.stdout.flush()
```

Does anybody have an alternative to print all of them in 3 lines?

Answer (score 1):

all the above correct. 
Just make sure to create some endpoint to the While loop.

```
import sys 
import time
import os 

def clear():
    os.system( 'cls' )

a = 1
b = 5
c =10

while c<20:
  sys.stdout.write("\r" "****************************\n") 
  sys.stdout.write("\r" "This is Run : " + str(a) + "\n")
  sys.stdout.write("\r" "****************************\n")
  sys.stdout.write("\r" " This is a : " + str(a) +  "\n This is b :" +  str(b) + "\n This is C:"  +str(c) + "\n" )

  time.sleep(2)

  a += 1
  b+=1
  c+=1
  sys.stdout.flush()
  clear()
```

Based on your reply I think this is what you looking for.
When I run it from console it clears the outputs.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't replace the lines, it starts a new

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the command `sys.std.write` is overwriting the outputs. The outputs are only getting cleared when you call `sys.stdout.flush()`. Although this command also just clears the **data buffer** which is the temporary region where python stores data temporarily. Therefore, hitting it will just put your cursor to new line i.e. equivalent to `\n` new line character.

So, basically you need to write a `\n` the new line character at the end of the string to show all inputs.

Also, if you want to clear the console you may use `os.system('clear')`.

You may refer the following code for a cleaner output.

```
import os
import sys
import time

a, b, c = 1, 5, 10

while True:
    sys.stdout.write(f"a:{a} b:{b} c:{c}\n")
    time.sleep(3)
    a += 1
    b += 1
    c += 1
    #clear console
    os.system('clear')
```

Comment: os.system('clear") or os.system('cls') doesnt clear the screen. I get an error code and it adds another line

Comment: Thk)) Hack with command "clear" == desired result.

Answer (score 0):

No, it **is** printing `a`, immediately overwriting it with `b` and then with `c`, so `c` is all you see.  The only way (aside from utilizing `curses` or some other advanced terminal capabilities) to have all three visible is to print them in single line like this:

```
sys.stdout.write("\r{} {} {}".format(a,b,c))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are only seeing the c as you mentioned, is because it is the last thing you wrote before calling `sys.stdout.flush()`

If you remove the part where `sys.stdout.write("\r" + str(c))` you will then see b

As @Błotosmętek mentioned and answered before me, you can format the required output and then perform the flush.